# Template alias in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm currently trying to port code to Visual Studio 2012 that makes use of template aliases, like this:

```
template< typename T > using SmartPtr = std::shared_ptr< T >;
```

However, Visual Studio 2012 does not support template aliases.

Is it possible to replace the above declaration with something equivalent that will not break the code that uses it?

Regards

Comment: Is it use in specialization ? Inheritance may be a work-around.

Answer (score 2):

```
template< typename T >
struct SmartPtr
{
    typedef std::shared_ptr< T > type;
};
```

Use it as:

```
SmartPtr<int>::type
```

Comment: But that would still mean I had to replace every instance in the code of SmartPtr<int> by SmartPtr<int>::type right?

Comment: @user5024425 yes but if you can't use template aliases that's what you have to do.

Comment: Hmm, what if I try inheritance: template< typename T > struct SmartPtr : public std::shared_ptr< T > {}; Can that provide problems?

Comment: @user5024425 this is runtime not compile time.

Comment: @user5024425 You need to pass-through the constructors.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using macros:

```
#define SmartPtr std::shared_ptr;
```

works the same as template aliasing on VS2015